# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'SmallIntegerField'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an attribute error while using 'SmallIntegerField'. Doesn't Serializer support 'SmallIntegerField'?

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer): 
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=150)
    batch = serializers.SmallIntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it works with ModelSerializer -

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'batch']
```